# Double centralizers in the Murphy book

Tags: operator-algebras, banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

I've been into this for days and days and I still can't see why, given the definition of $L^\ast$ as $L^\ast =(L(a^\ast))^\ast$  we get that $(LM)^\ast =L^\ast M^\ast$. Where is my mistake:

$$(LM)^\ast (a) =(L(a^\ast )M(a^\ast ))^\ast=(M(a^\ast ))^\ast  (L(a^\ast ))^\ast =M^\ast (a)L^\ast  (a)$$

This gives us $(LM)^\ast=M^\ast L^\ast$  which completely ruins the whole construction of the algebra of centralizers.
I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: @YACP G. J. Murphy, [C\*-algebras and Operator Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=emNvQgAACAAJ). It's a standard introductory book to the subject and thus quite unambiguous. But I agree: it would be better to mention the title.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplication of left centralizers is defined as *composition* $(LM)(a) = L(M(a))$, not pointwise multiplication $L(a)M(a)$. Notice that $L,M \colon A \to A$ are bounded linear maps.

Thus $(M^\ast(a))^\ast = M(a^\ast)$ yields
$$
(L^\ast M^\ast)(a) = L^\ast(M^\ast(a)) = (L[(M^\ast(a))^\ast])^\ast =  (L[M(a^\ast)])^\ast = ((LM)(a^\ast))^\ast= (LM)^\ast(a).
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, Martin!